# How to import project and print casted swift objects in xcode debugger (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, casting, lldb

I have attached debugger to running app. Now I'm trying to print casted Swift object in lldb console using these commands:

```
expr -l Swift -- import MyProjectName
expr -l Swift --  let $vc = unsafeBitCast(0x3daf26c078d8, ViewController.self)
expr -l Swift -- print($vc.view)
```

But I'm getting `error: no such module 'MyProjectName'` on 1st line.
Project name is matching with `.xcodeproj` and `.xcworkspace` files. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you don't run the first import line, just the rest? It shouldn't be necessary to import the app's main module. Have you altered any build systems related to debugging?

Comment: @DaveLee if I don't run the first import line than I get error: use of unresolved identifier 'ViewController'. I haven't altered build systems. The important thing is that I can attach phone with already running app and can't build app on phone directly from xcode (trying to fixe rare bug).